# What is the source of this image of Miles Morgan's "mark"?

Tags: colonial-america

[Miles Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miles_Morgan), one of the founders of Springfield, MA made a 'mark' which resembled an anchor (more than anything), though I read it was also compared to a pickaxe.  Sometime in the past few months I took a screen shot of this mark - and I have no record of where I found it? Can anyone point me in the right direction? I need to offer documentation of the image in a book I'm compiling.[image: image of a personal mark resembling an anchor]

Comment: An address for Istack imgur comes up when you double left click on the image

Comment: Perhaps this is a symbol used for signing documents with natives?  I don't see Miles listed here but on page 13 of this PDF the Agawam natives sign a contract similarly.  https://www.longmeadowhistoricalsociety.org/resources/350%20years%20of%20Springfield.pdf Perhaps you captured from a contract?

Comment: @JohnStrachan That's just where all images uploaded on this site end up; Stack Exchange have a private arrangement with [Imgur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imgur) which includes a dedicated server, hence the "stack" for "Stack Exchange" in the URL.

Comment: @IMSoP She might just have to look through her browser history then, and click on anything she does not recognise? She could narrow it down if she can remember what day it was, or at least what week it was.

Comment: Thank you all for your efforts - I did review my browser history and can't find anything on the date the image "says" it was added.  Hopefully when I least expect to find it I will, or I'll leave it out of the book.

Comment: When doing genealogical research, two locations I have noted signed documents would be *wills* and *deeds*. If you have a source discussing either of those for this individual review those sources. A facsimile copy of a signature from a deed might be included in a detailed location history, such as a History of Springfield book.  A specific family genealogy might include this type of information as well.